# Получение доступа к массиву RAID0 Linux с помощью Windows

Tags: linux, windows

**Задача:** получить доступ к массиву RAID0, который создан из 2х дисков на виртуальной машине Linux с помощью утилиты mdadm, из виртуальной машины Windows.

**Что сделано:** массив RAID0 из 2х дисков на виртуальной машине Linux с помощью утилиты mdadm, эти 2 диска подключены к виртуальной машине Windows. На Windows установлена программа Virtual Volume (http://www.chrysocome.net/virtualvolumes), которая согласно описанию может собрать и прочитать RAID0. При установке появляется графическая и консольная часть программы Virtual Volume  (vv и vv_cmd), я запускал vv_cmd и вводил команду 'show', согласно инструкции.

**Проблема:** Программа Virtual Volume не может собрать и прочитать массив RAID0, хотя все остальные разделы читает довольно хорошо.

**Вопрос:** Кто-то имел дело с этой программой? Может я что-то делаю не так? Или есть другие программные продукты Windows для этой задачи?

Comment: Я в своё время тоже задавался вопросм можно ли виндой прочитать линуксовый рейд (у меня был 5-й). В общем, если коротко, то нет. Было это недавно и сильно сомневаюсь, что с тех пор что-то поменялось. А нафига, если не секрет? Может есть другие подходы для решения задачи.

Comment: [увы, это не реализовано в ms/windows](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/5da803aa-767a-480b-81ae-7a53a6f370a4/mdadm-on-windows?forum=WindowsInsiderPreview). используйте *gnu/linux*, предоставляя доступ к данным по какому-нибудь реализованному в *ms/windows* сетевому файловому протоколу (smb, nfs, afs и т.п.)